# Laravel contar dias dentro de un periodo de fechas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo 2 calendarios uno fecha emisión y otro fecha expiración, quiero saber cuantos días hay entre las fechas colocadas y guardarla en una variable.

Por ejemplo si mi fecha emisión es `02/07/2017` y mi fecha expiración es `12/07/2017` la cantidad de días que hay entre fecha emisión y expiración son `10`.

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Fecha De Emision</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fecha_emision" name="fecha_emision" placeholder="AAAA/MM/DD" type="text"/>
      </div>
         </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label" for="date">Fecha De Expiracion</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fecha_expiracion" name="fecha_expiracion" placeholder="AAAA/MM/DD" type="text"/>
      </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para **PHP**: Utiliza [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Ejemplo:

```
$fechaEmision = Carbon::parse($req->input('fecha_emision'));
$fechaExpiracion = Carbon::parse($req->input('fecha_expiracion'));

$diasDiferencia = $fechaExpiracion->diffInDays($fechaEmision);
```

Para **JS**: Utiliza [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Ejemplo:

```
var fechaEmision = moment(document.getElementById('fecha_emision').value, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
var fechaExpiracion = moment(document.getElementById('fecha_expiracion').value, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var diasDiferencia = fechaExpiracion.diff(fechaEmision, 'days');
```

Comment: Exelente Gracias !!!